# Not able to write to a file via command line

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to log a python script. When the script is as follows there is no issue while logging:-

```
print('Test')
```

But when I enclose it in a while loop and sleep then it does not log the output for some reason.

```
while(1):
    print('Test')
    time.sleep(3600)
```

I am using Ubuntu and the command I run to log is:-

```
python3 script.py > /home/usr/Test.txt
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Comment: Also when you use only one `>` on linux you are overwriting the file. you have to use two `>>` to append to file.

Comment: I don't mind overwriting the file. I just don't understand why the line Test is not written at all in the txt file when enclosed in a loop.

Comment: Try to change the time to 1 second and see what happens. You have to exit the program before anything happens, because bash/ubuntu is waiting for your program to finish before it will write anything.

Comment: what do u mean by **while(1)** the int **1** represents what?

Answer (score 0):

So when you write to a file from bash like this, you will not get any output before your program has finished, so maybe it will be better to let python write to the file from within its own code.

Here is an example:

```
import time

while True:
    new_data = 'hello fello!'
    with open('file.txt', 'a+') as f:
        f.write(new_data+'\n')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Notice I added a newline `\n` after the new data to prevent everything being on the same line

the parameter `'a'` in the `open()` means to append to the file, the `+` means also to read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush the stream, to make sure it's written immediately.

```
import time
import sys

while True:
    print('Test')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.seep(3600)
```